# Node.js - submit form

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, submit

I use node.js and express. When I press the button (btnSend), I want to send data to node.js by express (without refresh the page). How do I send data using jQuery?

```
<form action="/Send" method="post">
Username: 
<input type="text" name="user" id="txtUser" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSend" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is off topic, but consider wrapping "Username: " and the text input element with a [label tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/label).  It makes the form a bit more semantic and usable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a rough outline of what your jQuery should look like:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the page from refreshing
    var $this = $(this); // `this` refers to the current form element
    $.post(
        $this.attr("action"), // Gets the URL to sent the post to
        $this.serialize(), // Serializes form data in standard format
        function(data) { /** code to handle response **/ },
        "json" // The format the response should be in
    );
});
```

This code snippet finds all form elements on the page and listens for a submit event from them.  A form can be submit in a number ways (e.x. clicking a submit button, hitting enter, etc...), so for the sake of usability, it's best to listen for submit events directly opposed to listening for click events key on submit buttons.

When a submit event does occurs, the code above first prevents the default browser actions (which among other things refreshes the page) by calling [`e.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault).  It then uses [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to send the form data to the url specified in the action attribute.  Note that [`$.fn.serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) is used to serialize the form data in a standard format.

Your express code should look something like this:

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.bodyParser()); // Automatically parses form data

app.post('/Send', function(req, res){ // Specifies which URL to listen for
  // req.body -- contains form data
});

app.listen(3000);
```

The documentation on `express.bodyParser` is a bit sparse, but after a bit of [code spelunking](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/urlencoded.js#L47) it looks like it uses [node-querystring](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-querystring) underneath the covers.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the client-side response function to fire.   function(data) { /** code to handle response **/ }, Do you need to add a res.end() or some such to the client side code?

Comment: No you shouldn't have to call `res.end` on the client side -- only on the server side.  In chrome's dev console, I would in the network tab and make sure the post request is completing without error.  Also take a look at your server side response code (i.e. the code in the `// req.body -- contains form data` function) and make sure you're ending your response correctly. Hope that helps.

Comment: I was able to narrow down the issue, and it's unrelated to this question. For some reason the app is unable to find fs.appendfile when using forever but it works fine when using nodemon.